# Delete item from core data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swift3

I have a fucntion that returns me some strings

```
func getURLsToSend () {
    //create a fetch request, telling it about the entity
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<URLsToSend> = URLsToSend.fetchRequest()

    do {
        //Get results
        let searchResults = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

        //You need to convert to NSManagedObject to use 'for' loops
        for urls in searchResults as [NSManagedObject] {
            //get the Key Value pairs (although there may be a better way to do that...
            print("\(urls.value(forKey: "url"))")

            //Process URL

            //Delete from Core Data

        }
    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
}
```

As you can see in the comments after I've found each string (it's a url) I need to be able to process it and then delete it.

I'm OK processing what I have that's fine I just have no idea how to go about deleting object from core data can somebody shed some light for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realised my mistake, I needed to do

```
context = getContext()
```

and then I was able to simply do

```
context.delete(urls)
```